# Finding the count of a given word using a wordclass

Tags: java, object

I have an assignment where I have to create 3 classes Oblig6(main method), Word(Ord) and Wordlist(Ordliste). I have to find the number of times a word is repeated in a text using the word class.

I have a problem formulating the following segment. I need the word class to make a new object of the given word if it's already in the wordlist(ArrayLis ordliste), and then next time it finds the same word in the text, it has to add 1 to the total amount for that specific object defined by Ord(String s). I know that i'm creating a new object every time it finds a word that is in the wordlist, i need a suggestion on how to formulate it correctly.
Here is my code.

The wordlist class, the main problem is in void fraOrdtilOrdliste.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ordliste {
private ArrayList<String> ord = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> ordliste = new ArrayList<String>();
private int i = 0;
private int totalord = 0;
private int antallforekomster = 0;


// Reads the provided txt file and puts the words into a word list

void lesBok(String filnavn) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner innlestfil = new Scanner(file);
    while (innlestfil.hasNextLine()) {
        ord.add(innlestfil.nextLine());
    }
}

// Reads ord arryalist and compares the words to ordliste arraylist, adds them if they are not  inn it all ready
//If they are there, crates a new Ord(String s)object of that words and adds to amount.
void fraOrdtilOrdliste () {
    ordliste.add(ord.get(i));
    for (i=0;i<ord.size();i++) {
        Boolean unik = true;
        for (int j = 0; j<ordliste.size();j++) {
            if (ordliste.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase(ord.get(i))) {
                unik = false;
                new Ord(ordliste.get(j)).oekAntall();
            }
        }
        if (unik) {
            ordliste.add(ord.get(i));
        }
    }

}

// Using the Ord class as a counter for this method. If the word is registerd beforhand it will add 1.

void leggTilOrd(String s) {
    for (i = 0; i < ord.size(); i++) {
        if (ord.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            ord.add(i, s);
            System.out.println("Suksess");
        } else if (!ord.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            new Ord(s).oekAntall();
            System.out.println("Antall okt");
            return;
        }
    }
}

// Searches for the word in the wordlist and returns null if it does not exist.
Ord finnOrd(String s) {
    for (i = 0; i < ord.size(); i++) {
        if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase(ord.get(i))) {
            System.out.println("null");
            return null;
        } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(ord.get(i))) {
            System.out.println("Fant ordet");
        }

    }
    return null;
}

// Prints out the total amount of words in the word list.
int antallOrd() {
    for (i = 0; i < ordliste.size(); i++) {
        totalord++;
    }
    System.out.println("Antall ord i ordlisten er: " + totalord);
    return totalord;
}

// Counts the total amounts of a word in the word list.
int antallForekomster(String s){
   antallforekomster= new Ord(s).hentAntall();
   System.out.println("Ordet forekommer " + antallforekomster + " ganger");
   return antallforekomster;
}
```

Hers is the word class.

Comment: I dont understand. Why dont you just pass the entire text to the word class in a static method that returns a Map of word to count?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm pretty new to programming. If you are talking about why i don't use a hashmap, it's because i'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, let me give it a shot, because i am not even sure i am reading your code correctly.

a) Define a class Word that has one member variable for the count and one member variable for the String word.

b) In your wordlist class have a member variable that is a List. Every time you parse a word out, loop through the List comparing the string you have with the string of the word. If matches, increment the count in the word class.

The loop sounds really ineffecient, but if you use a List then thats all you can really do. So your performance is basically O(nsquare) where n is the number of words in the text given.

WordList Class :

```
public class WordList {
    static List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    public static void countWord(String inputWord) {
        for (Word word : words) {
            if (word.getWord().equals(inputWord)) {
                word.setCount(word.getCount() + 1);
            } else {
                Word newWord = new Word();
                newWord.setWord(inputWord);
                newWord.setCount(1);
                words.add(newWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Word Class :

```
public class Word {
    String word;
    int count;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are actually reading the code correctly, i'm 99% certain that the problem is that the loop makes a new object word every time it finds a word in the ordliste arraylist that is the same as a word in the ord arraylist it creates a new object of the word insted of finding the old object of that word and adding 1 to count. I need help formulating this

Comment: Don't bother with efficiency, this is from a beginner class in java programming at my university, we have not started to focus on efficiency yeat.

Comment: I added some sample code for the WordList and Word class. It should work but i havent tested it. btw, specifically which part of your code is the loop you are referring to in your comment "the loop makes a new object word every time..."

Comment: If you look in the class Ordliste and find the method fraOrdtilOrdliste, which is the second method, then you will find it in the second for loop. 
if (statement)
new Ord(statement).oekantall

Comment: hmmm...perhaps the problem is that you are adding to the list in the first statement ordliste.add(ord.get(i)); how do you add a word to the ordlist before checking whether it exists in the list already. maybe i am misreading that code.

Comment: the ordliste(wordlist) arraylist starts empty so the first word in ord arraylist will be the first word in tha ordliste arraylist

Comment: Yes, and that seems to be the discrepancy. Why two? ord arraylist and ordliste arraylist? shouldnt the ord (word) class simply be a data object that has a count of itself and a string representing itself?

Comment: Yeas you are correct, i figured it out, this question is solved.